# "Element EditText is not allowed here" inside a TextInputLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the recent `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` feature to get [floating labels](http://www.google.fr/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels) in Android.

By looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) it seems that you're supposed to put your `EditText` with the `android:hint="myFloatingLabel"` inside a `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` element to benefit from it.

Functionally this works when I test it, but in Android Studio I get a warning on the `EditText`:
"Element EditText is not allowed here"
The consequence (besides the fact that I have annoying warnings) is that it breaks all code completion (for string resources, for id resources, etc).

Is it an Android Studio bug, or did I miss something?

My code sample for information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is valid XML and similar one "works" fine for me, incl. autocompletion

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of days ago. I don't remember the exact procedure to solve it. I updated android studio and used the last version of `buildToolsVersion`. At the end I invalidated the Android Studio caches

Comment: @Joseph82 I already updated Android Studio, used the latest Build Tools versions (I even tested with 23.0.0 rc2), and tried invalidating/restarting Android Studio, but the problem persists :(

Comment: I know that can be sound very strange, but I solve the problem changing the parent of my app theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Then changing back to my first theme the problem does not arise anymore.

Comment: Updating to `Android Studio 1.2.2` fixed my issue (this update was released today)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing to these versions. It worked for me.

```
compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Comment: I think right when SDK 22 went out, I had tried again and it did not work. However I just tried again right now (with SDK 23) and it works just fine.

Answer (score 16):

Try using **`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`** instead of **`EditText`**:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I had the same issue and this did the job for me.

Comment: Thanks. However, the official Android documentation linked in my original post clearly states that the `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` element should wrap a `android.widget.EditText`. So your solution is more a workaround.

Comment: @jdebon that is incorrect.  The Android documentation states that the TextInputLayout wraps an EditText OR a descendant.

Comment: This help me with doing the same for `AutoCompleteTextView`

Answer (score 2):

add the following line to your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

It works for me.

Comment: Seems that this library tells Android Studio to understand where EditText can be used? But EditText is pretty standard, hence the question: why does this work? +1

Answer (score 2):

Came across this old question while trying to find out how to get `TextInputEditText` inside `TextInputLayout` to be allowed and shown in the Android Studio layout preview.

The error **"Not allowed here"** disappeared after *"running Invalidate Caches / Restart..."* as mentioned by Frankie D

However, the preview still did not show up, until I changed the view to properly link to the design support lib as:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
... />
```

The new TextInputEditText has a few fixes and cool features as explained on https://www.journaldev.com/14748/android-textinputlayout-example

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with PreferenceScreen in Android Studio 3.0

Comment: @JoseRicardoCiterioAlcala Is your PreferenceScreen based on the old PreferencesActivity? The support design elements probably only work inside the newer support Activity class. I haven't done it yet, but I think there is a PreferenceFragment that you could switch to in order to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, I see sun, I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem, not only on EditText but also on CheckBox and Button. Finally fixed it by running Invalidate Caches / Restart...  Maybe some of the previous solutions also worked because they resulted in the caches being cleared.

Comment: This is Intellij specific, you should mention it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` with `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`

Answer (score -1):

TextInputLayout is a new element introduced in Design Support library to display the floating label in EditText.

In Android, one of the most basic UI element or widgets is an EditText. It is generally used to take the any kind of input from the user but what it lacks was a label attached to it.
https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/textinputlayout-floating-labels-edittext

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Change EditText with android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.

Than it will work for you...

Comment: This was already proposed in a richer answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32964485/4345848